# should I resize images for displaying in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiimageview, tableview

I am using a tableView that among other things display images in a UITableViewController.  The images are locally stored and quite large so that they may if clicked be displayed full screen.  The tableView cell has a small preview of these images.

When storing these images locally, is it better to store two versions?  A thumbnail and a full image purely for the performance of the tableView?  Or will that not effect the scrolling etc to have just the one full image and allow the tableView cell to resize the image to display at the reduced size?

I will not be uploading/downloading so this question is not about creating thumbnails to optimize download transfers.

I am just interested in whether it is best practice to create a thumbnail for tableView controller cell's.

Also, I am familiar with setting aspectFit for the imageView to get the correct size.  Just wondering if I should be carrying two images for better performance or if it doesn't make any difference and not necessary to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am just interested in whether it is best practice to create a thumbnail for tableView controller cells

Yes! It is best practice to create a thumbnail for *any* image display, *especially* table view cells. To hand an image view an image that is too large is a *massive* waste of memory and other resources.

See [*Image and Graphics Best Practices*](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/219/) from WWDC 2018 for details.

Comment: that video was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.  The code at 10:44 into the video even shows you how to create the thumbnail in an optimal manner.

Comment: Yep, exactly. Use the ImageIO framework and you never even have to load the original image into memory.

Comment: This video was super helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: @mumush Yeah, I knew about the ImageIO framework, but the video gives some tweaks I’d never realized before.